# Create a unified RSS feed for Blog Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed, blog-overflow

There does not seem to be a unified RSS for all the community blogs. There should be.

Even if I don't participate in the communities, I do find many blog posts general enough to be interesting. It's a pain to keep track of all these sites.

Can we have an aggregated feed of all the sites' blogs, that I can subscribe to, without having to keep track of any new blogs that the communities choose to create?

Comment: Have started on this.  Might be live next week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A feed for all the blogs listed on http://blogoverflow.com is now available.

This includes the primary [blog.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com), as well as the blogs for [Server Fault](http://blog.serverfault.com), [Super User](http://blog.superuser.com), and SE 2.0 sites that have blogs.

http://blogoverflow.com/feed/network